# Уменьшение блока и увеличение картинки при наведении на первый

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.test {
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.test:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
.test img {
    margin: 100px;
    transition: 1s;
    width: 50rem;
}
.test img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img style="width: 400px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP46lQKg17HWmKMsToy49X1cAAmGvIEQgA8Q&usqp=CAU"> 
</div>
```

Как одновременно уменьшить блок и увеличить картинку?

Comment: а чем не устраивает то, что вы сделали?

Comment: нужно одновременно уменьшить блок и увеличить картинку при на ведении только на блок, а не на картинку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так устроит?

основной смысл - вы все завязываете на наведение на родительский блок и все дочерние элементы отсчитываете от него, т.е.

```
parent {
}

parent:hover {
}

parent child {
}

parent:hover child {
}
```

т.е. не `parent child:hover`, а именно `parent:hover child`

```css
.test {
    background-color: black;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding:  10px;
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    width:    300px;
    height:   200px;
}

.test:hover {
    transform:  scale(0.75);
}

.test img {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 25%;

  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.test:hover img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP46lQKg17HWmKMsToy49X1cAAmGvIEQgA8Q&usqp=CAU"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Я понял в чём нюанс. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Как бы я сделал:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.test {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.test::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.test > img {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.test:hover::before {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.test:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP46lQKg17HWmKMsToy49X1cAAmGvIEQgA8Q&usqp=CAU">
</div>
```

Поправил ваш код,
`.test:hover img`, а не `.test img:hover`

```css
.test {
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.test:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
.test img {
    margin: 100px;
    transition: 1s;
    width: 50rem;
}
.test:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img style="width: 400px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP46lQKg17HWmKMsToy49X1cAAmGvIEQgA8Q&usqp=CAU"> 
</div>
```